# Calling an API Get with RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

So I have the following API end point. It works when called from postman and swagger.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/GetPersonList")]
public class GetPersonListController : Controller
{
 

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PersonList([FromQuery] PersonListRequest personListRequest)
    {
 
           //Do stuff to set distilleryResults
            return Ok(personResults);
    }
}
```

But when I call it from a c#, I can not get it working or get some odd code smells.

Adding the parameters one at a time works, but I'm not sure if it’s the preferred way?

First off this block of code works, but doing request.AddParameter feels like a code smell.

```
// Set the base URL of the API
string baseUrl = "https://localhost:1234";

// Create a new RestSharp client
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);

// Create a new RestSharp request
var request = new RestRequest("/api/GetPersonList", Method.Get);
 

// Add query parameters to the request
request.AddParameter("PersonName", searchRequest.PersonName);
request.AddParameter("Country", searchRequest.Country);
request.AddParameter("Region", searchRequest.Region);           

request.AddObject(searchRequest);                   
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

I have tried replacing the AddParameter with one of these.

```
request.AddBody(searchRequest); 
request.AddJsonBody(searchRequest);
```

But each one I get the same error.  This makes me think there is something I have done wrong in the API set up.

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.'
```

I have some luck with

```
request.AddObject(searchRequest);
```

But if I don’t fill in every field, I get the following error, which is a little odd?  Do I have to decorate my PersonListRequest model with some attributes?

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-457f493633b35a00b17ab641a4612bbf-85d7ac54f7448abc-00",
    "errors": {
        "Region": [
            "The Region field is required."
        ],
        "Country": [
            "The Country field is required."
        ],
        "PersonName": [
            "The PersonName field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

So the questions are, how do you call a Get API endpoint with RestSharp.  While passing an object that does not have every property filled in?

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing up a lot here. You cannot replace `AddParameter()` with `AddBody()` because they are very different things. One adds query parameters which will be placed in the URL, the other adds a HTTP request body to the request. As the error tells you, you cannot have a request body for `GET` requests, so therefore that's expected behavior.

`AddParameter()` does unfortunately not have an override to add multiple parameters at once e.g. using a `Dictionary`. But you can use the `RestRequest` objects `Parameter` property to add multiple parameters at once. Or you could of course create an extension method on `RestRequest` which takes multiple parameters.

An extension method could look like this:

```cs
using RestSharp;

public static class RestRequestExtensions
{
    public static RestRequest AddParameters(this RestRequest request, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        request.Parameters.AddParameters(parameters);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Also, to see what the request URL is gonna be you can use `BuildUri()`. This will also show you why your other attempts have not worked, since the URL differs and your API is expected the parameters to be present in the URL.

Last but not least, no the API response is not *odd*. It is exactly what you would expect. [HTTP status code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means *Bad Request*, which indicates an error on the client side e.g. that parameters that should have been supplied in a different way were not properly supplied, as was the case with your request. You are also missing one required parameter `Region`, which you need to add.

I'd recommend you familiarize yourself a bit more with the HTTP protocol, its methods and what they support and are supposed to do.

Here an updated version of your code including everything I have mentioned that should work.

```cs
var baseUrl = "https://localhost:1234";
// Create a new RestSharp client
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
// Create a new RestSharp request
var request = new RestRequest("/api/GetPersonList", Method.Get);

var region = "asia"; // region is also required!
var personName = "Peter";
var country = "Netherlands";
// Add all query parameters at once (without using the extension method)
request.Parameters.AddParameters(new QueryParameter[]{
    new("PersonName", personName),
    new("Region", region),
    new("Country", country)
});
// Alternatively with extension method
// request.AddParameters(new QueryParameter[]{
//     new("PersonName", personName),
//     new("Region", region),
//     new("Country", country)
// });
// You can check the URL the request will go to like this
Console.WriteLine(client.BuildUri(request));
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

You are also missing error handling, i. e. checking whether the request completed and if it did checking the HTTP status code to be able to judge if everything went as expected. Please see the [RestSharp docs on error handling](https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks for that reply.  I had missed out Region from my example, when cutting up my code and making it a generic example.  I stripped out error handling stuff   to keep my example.    I just want to say all the fields are not required, I could just ask for all the people in the Netherlands by just setting country and leaving the other fields blank.

Comment: In that case you need to adjust your API endpoint to [make those optional](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2020/02/15/asp-net-how-to-create-a-controller-action-with-optional-parameters/) by assigning a default value or making them nullable and then obviously handle that accordingly when handling the request.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, it was to change api model and make the properties nullable.  I did that and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your code below

```
// Add query parameters to the request
request.AddParameter("PersonName", searchRequest.PersonName);
request.AddParameter("Country", searchRequest.Country);
request.AddParameter("Region", searchRequest.Region);           

request.AddObject(searchRequest);
```

The code above adds the same parameters twice as all `AddObject` does is add every property it could find as a query parameter (for GET requests).

```
var result = await client.GetJsonAsync<YourResponseType>("/api/GetPersonList", searchRequest.Region);
```

I am not sure why you tried `AddBody` and `AddJsonBody` as your own API expects the request model to be populated from query.

Concerning the validation, I can invite you to read the model validation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute), the "Non-nullable reference types and [Required] attribute". Although you haven't provided code for `PersonListRequest`, I suspect that every property there is not nullable, and that's why you are getting validation errors.